# Capturar imagens da webcam a cada 1 segundo usando JavaCV

Tags: java, opencv

Um determinado programador está fazendo um projeto em que a webcam padrão tira fotos a cada 1 segundo utilizando o JavaCV.

Por enquanto ,nesse code, ao clique do botão capturar ele captura uma foto e salva na pasta do programa. Pede-se que o programa salve as fotos em uma determinada pasta selecionada pelo usuário e que a webcam capture fotos a cada 1 segundo.

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;    
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;    
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;    
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui;    
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.CvCapture;    
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvSaveImage;    
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;    
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aperte a tecla P para parar a gravação");
        while(KeyEvent.VK_P){

try{
            grabber.start();

IplImage img = grabber.grab();

            if(img!=null){
                cvSaveImage("image1.jpg", img);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setFocusable(true);
        setVisible(true);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a classe `Timer` para isso.

Só basta criar um `Timer`, e setar um `TimerTask` que faça o que você precisa dentro do método `run()`, por exemplo:

```
Timer timer;

public void criarTimer(int segundos) {
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Time's up!");
        }
    };
    int segundosParaComecar = 0;
    int segundosParaCapturar = segundos*1000;
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, segundosParaComecar, segundosParaCapturar);
}
```

[Veja funcionando no IdeOne.](http://ideone.com/XeKHHn)

E outra coisa. Se precisar cancelar o timer, eu aconselho a deixar uma variavel global, e fazer uma condição dentro do `run()` do `TimerTask`, assim você pode dar um `timer.cancel()` quando quiser.